# Is it sensible to always assume that the "usual conditions" always hold?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I've read in several places that it is reasonable to assume that the usual conditions (that the filtered space is complete, and that the filtration is right-continuous) hold since one can always minimally modify the setting one is working in so that they do hold (simply complete the space and replace the filtration with its right limit).

I've also been told that modellers can find doing the above unnatural since, for example, there is no reason the information available to us at time zero should include that about events that happen in the future, even if they have zero probability of occurring. More specifically, suppose that $X$ is a real-valued process on some filtered space $(\Omega,\cal{F},\cal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$, $B$ is some Borel set and that $\mathbb{P}[X_T\in B]=0$ for some fixed $T>0$. Then it seems a bit bizarre to assume that $\{X_T\in B\}\in \cal{F}_0$, that is, that at time zero we know whether or not $\{X_T\in B\}$ has happened.

However, I don't know enough of the big picture to grasp the real consequences and potential issues of assuming that the usual conditions hold. Could someone explain them or a few of them? I'm not talking about the technical advantages of assuming that they do hold (I'm thinking of asking a second separate question about this), but more something like "can we ever find ourselves in a situation we where assuming they do hold is problematic and there is no easy way around the issue?".

Comment: @ jkn : maybe to make you a little more comfortable with the "usual conditions" you might note (see Protter for example) that a lot of interesting process (to wit Feller Processes) fulfill naturally the usual conditions. These are here in the first place to be able to work without too much technicalities with càdlàg versions semi-martingales. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: Hi, thanks for the reply. The thing is I'm dealing with a class of Markov processes for which I'm not sure whether the usual conditions hold (for example I haven't been able to deduce yet whether or not they are feller); they come from systems biology and I haven't really seen them discussed in a rigorous setting, hence the question.

Comment: @ jkn: Although I don't have any counterexample at hand, I think that Feller property is really important to fulfill the usual conditions. If you can't show that your process is Feller then and I'm not sure you will be able to avoid (maybe hard) technicalities to show that you have a càdlàg process at hand (or that there exists a version of it which is càdlàg). Maybe you could tell what is the transition semigroup associated to your processes. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge, thanks for the replies, I've been working towards showing that the semigroup is feller (its defined in terms of its generator, so I'm trying to apply Hille-Yosida). I might post it in a bit -- I need to find a concise way to describe it first.